# WebDriverException: Unexpected token ':'. Expected ')' to end a argument list when using jQuery :contains with Selenium

Tags: jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code:

```
String jquery = "$(h4:contains('im looking for this')).get(0)";
WebElement element = (WebElement)((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript(jquery);
```

and I get this error:

> WebDriverException: Unexpected token ':'. Expected ')' to end a argument list.

I don't know why my jQuery string is incorrect/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing quotes around the whole selector:

```
String jquery = "$(\"h4:contains('im looking for this')\").get(0)";
```